# How to run TFLite network on Android phone GPU?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I used tensorflow example tutorial on Object detection and it works, but when Im trying to add GpuDelegate it breaks:

```
try {
  GpuDelegate delegate = new GpuDelegate();
  Interpreter.Options options = (new Interpreter.Options()).addDelegate(delegate);
  d.tfLite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(assetManager, modelFilename),options);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

with error `cannot find symbol class GpuDelegate`

I am pretty new to Java and Android and my guess it has something to do with the imports? So here are my imports:

```
package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite;

import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Trace;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.env.Logger;
```

and in `org.tensorflow.lite` there is no `GpuDelegate`

Could I get directions on how to solve this problem?

Edit:
Here are dependencies inside build.gradle(:app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation('org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly') { changing = true }
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: What dependency have u used inside build.gradle file for tf- lite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use GpuDelegate class you have to import these dependencies inside app build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
...
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly'
}
```